# Read all network connections

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I want to read a programs network connections and list them up. But i have absolutely no idea how to do so. Hooking the socket functions is not very clever.

I need this to write a private server.

Freaky

Comment: Are the network connections in your own program, or in another program? Also, what operating system is your target?

Comment: Do you mean something like `netstat` on Linux?

Comment: Nice question. Perhaps you can read the source of ss. [https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c) Also try reading [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: My operating system is Windows. This is not my own program, else i would definitely know where i am connecting to/what i am sending - Debugging would be easy then.

Comment: Try launch `netstat /a` in command prompt.